# UDP STM32- Error: Destination host unreachable

Tags: udp, stm32

I am trying to establish UDP communication in the stm32 NUCLEO-F746ZG board. But I'm not able to ping. Getting the message as "Destination host unreachable." The program not going inside udp_echoserver_receive_callback() function.

```
int main(void)
    {

  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_LWIP_Init();
  while (1)
  {
      MX_LWIP_Process();
  }
}


void udp_echoserver_init(void)
{
     struct udp_pcb *upcb;
       err_t err;
       upcb = udp_new();

       if (upcb)
       {
           ip_set_option(upcb, SOF_BROADCAST);
          err = udp_bind(upcb, IP_ADDR_ANY, 80);

          if(err == ERR_OK)
          {

            udp_recv(upcb, udp_echoserver_receive_callback, NULL);
          }
          else
          {
            udp_remove(upcb);
          }
       }
}

void udp_echoserver_receive_callback(void *arg, struct udp_pcb *upcb, struct pbuf *p, const ip_addr_t *addr, u16_t port)
{
  pc = (char*)p->payload;
  pbuf_free(p);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Did you configure static ip address or do you use DHCP? Are you sure you are pinging correct address?

Comment: configured static ip address